# PInvoke/Interop Declaration

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke

I'm attempting to use the libgsasl library from managed code in Mono.  I have some other calls working, but this particular one is giving me fits.  I continually receive an exception that I "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."  This is obviously NOT good.  I believe my issue may be in the double indirection Gsasl_session parameter, but I am not sure.

The native function is defined as this:

> ```
> extern GSASL_API int gsasl_client_start (Gsasl * ctx, const char *mech,
>                      Gsasl_session ** sctx);
> ```

I have defined the managed extern as this:

> ```
> [DllImport("libgsasl-7.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
> [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
> [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
> public static extern int gsasl_client_start(
>     GsaslContext context,
>     string mechanism,
>     ref GsaslSession session);
> ```

GsaslContext and GsaslSession are classes inheriting from SafeHandle.

You can see the use of this method in the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/doxygen/).

Comment: Is `Gsasl_session` in native code actually a `HANDLE` value?

Comment: Well, that's a good question.  It simply holds a reference to some memory.  As such, it can be addressed using an IntPtr, so I made the assumption that that was valid.

Comment: I'm actually unsure if it's valid or not to use a `SafeHandle` for a non-HANDLE value. I'm fairly certain this is legal though but wanted to ask in case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not sure what I just did, but apparently my issue was elsewhere, as is always the case when posting a question to SO.

I was creating the GsaslContext using a different function called gsasl_init (previously defined as this).

> ```
>     [DllImport("libgsasl-7.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
>     [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
>     [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
>     public static extern int gsasl_init(ref GsaslContext context);
> ```

When I changed that method call to an out instead of a ref, the subsequent call to gsasl_client_start began working correctly.  I'm not exactly sure what the difference is other than I may have been double allocating memory and then providing gsasl_client_start with the incorrect memory address for the GsaslContext.  Regardless, things seems to be working now.  If anyone has any insights into this, please leave another answer and I'll mark it up.

Comment: Mysterious how CharSet.Auto could work, it must be Ansi.